# how to count identical words in collections groovy during convertion collection to map

Tags: groovy

I have list, it should be converted to map where the key is elements of collection and value is a count of entrance of this elements.

I tried to do like this, but it leads to inconsistent result:

```
def list = ["first","first","second"]
def mapList = [:]

mapList = list.collectEntries{
    [(it):list.count{it}]
}
```

result:

```
{"first":3,"second":3}
```

expected result:

```
{"first":2, "second":1}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
list.countBy { it }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collection.groupBy(closure)` first to group result to `Map<String, List<String>>` by value and in the end you can trasform this map to `Map<String, Integer>` like:

```
list.groupBy { it }.collectEntries { k,v -> [(k): v.size()]}
```

For given input it will produce following output:

```
[first:2, second:1]
```

Alternatively you can use Java Stream API:

```
list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(), 
            Collectors.counting()
        ))
```

It will produce the same result, but significantly more efficient for huge data sets.